# React js in java webservice - gitIgnore

Tags: java, reactjs, gitignore

i have  tough nut to crack. I need to create first UI to my webservice (springboot, jpa, rest controller, h2). I need to use react js first time in my life. I have a problem how to start with this but i found information that i need to add some elements to gitignore file. That should be some react js files i think? Maybe somebody know what should I add to gitignore.

Comment: gitignore is the least of your problems in this story. It simply specifies which files are to be ignored regarding git. Forget this step and start with the real work.

Comment: There's also lots of gitignore templates available online (e.g.: via https://www.gitignore.io/ )